# Container to Container Networking and Sticky Session

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a setup with two applications running on cloud foundry. Application G works as reverse proxy with public route. Application A with internal route runs behind G. Container to Container Networking has been set between G and A. Now due to scaling, A has multiple instances. I need sticky session for A. But the problem is C2C networking does not go through Go Router so let A set JSessionID cookie does not work here. How to make sticky session happens?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic to your application will look like this:

```
Browser -> load balancer -> Gorouter -> App G (reverse proxy) -> App A
```

1. If App A is setting the cookie JSESSIONID as its session cookie, that will still trigger Gorouter's sticky session support, however, it will only apply to App G, which doesn't really help in this case.

   This is also something you need to consider if you scale out App G in the future because you probably don't want or need that since your reverse proxy won't be storing state in the session. You could change this behavior by using something other than JSESSIONID as your session cookie or having your reverse proxy rewrite the session cookie name.
2. In terms of having sticky session support for App A, you need to configure your reverse proxy i.e. App G to do this. How you do that depends on your reverse proxy, which you didn't specify in your original post. Check the docs for your reverse proxy for instructions on enabling "session persistence" or "sticky session" support.

Comment: App G is based on Spring Cloud Gateway. The question is how to make Spring Cloud gateway know which instance of App G to forward the request to.

Comment: Also for App A, one request login and create session on instance A1, but next request could be sent to instance A2 which does not share the session with A1, so change the cookie JSESSIONID to different cookie name does not help here.

Comment: The best case would be to use a shared session state (Redis/Geode/etc..). Then you don't need to worry about sticky sessions. I believe you can do sticky sessions with Gateway, although I haven't done it myself. Check out https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/689 and https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#same-instance-preference-for-loadbalancer.